# Do in game traps scale to difficulty?

Tags: diablo-iii

The traps that are set up in the game, such as log traps and for the achievement "Light Entertainment" where you have to kill 666 enemies with the chandeliers.

Do they Scale due to difficulty?
Can they one shot an enemy?

Comment: You can use abilities to get the monsters low enough for the trap to deal the killing blow (and yes, it counts towards the achievement).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Traps scale with difficulty, but not in relation to monster health - while traps on Inferno can do upwards of 40,000 damage, this is rarely enough to eliminate monsters that often have upwards of 80,000-100,000 health in Act 1.

Answer (score 2):

I can say for certain that chandeliers one-shot the weaker zombies in nightmare, but not the stronger types of monsters.

I remember them as one-shotting everything in normal, so if they do scale in damage with the difficulty, it's not quite enough to keep up with the increases in monster health.